# Is there analogue of four vertex theorem for Riemannian 2-sphere $(S^2,g)$?

Tags: riemannian-geometry

When I read the Four Vertex Theorem, I think that there may be analogue for smooth Riemannian 2-sphere $(S^2,g)$. Namely, assume the Gauss curvature of $(S^2,g)$ is $K$, Then, K has at least six extreme points on $(S^2,g)$, is it ?

Comment: H.Gluck, "The Generalized Minkowski Problem in Differential Geometry in the Large", Annals of Mathematics, 1972, Vol. 96, No. 2, pp. 245-276

Comment: @MoisheKohan  So, if the Gauss curvature change sign,  it is open ?

Comment: Chang, Sy.A., Yang, P.C. *Prescribing Gaussian curvature on $S^2$* . Acta Math. 159, 215–259 (1987) might be of interest

Comment: @Didier  Thanks, prescring curvature problem seemly be popular in the past.

Comment: @EnhaoLan It still is a very popular topic (see [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1903.06502), or [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/2206.12854), or [this](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00526-019-1584-2)...)

Comment: Yes, the existence of a metric on $S^2$ with prescribed Gaussian curvature is called "Nierenberg's Problem" and it is open, even though much is known. A discrete version of this problem (spherical metrics with conical singularities) was recently solved, but the answer is complicated as there are obstructions beyond the Gauss-Bonnet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of showing that the Gaussian curvature function on the 2-sphere may have as few as $2$ critical points is to use Gluck's result from

> Gluck, Herman.
> The generalized Minkowski problem in differential geometry in the large.
> Ann. of Math. (2) 96 (1972), 245–276.

Gluck showed that any positive function on the sphere can be realized as the Gaussian curvature of an embedding in 3-space (in fact his result is more general).  Thus, if one chooses a rotationally-symmetric function which is $1$ at the south pole and from there increases to the value $2$ at the north pole (in such a way that the gradient is nonzero everywhere except the two poles), one will obtain a metric with only two critical points (a maximum and a minimum).

Comment: Thank you, I was just finishing Gluck's result when I saw your answer.  If the Gauss curvature change sign, there must be at least four vertex ? (in terms of geometric intuition)

Comment: That's a good question.  Further results on realisation of curvature functions are in Kazdan-Warner (Curvature Functions for Compact 2-Manifolds, from '74).  I suggest you check there.

Comment: Great paper, I intuitively feel why using PDE for geometry. Thanks again.

Comment: As far as your question is concerned, one can use rotationally symmetric metrics in which case the PDE problem reduces to an ODE, so the corresponding answers probably don't need the full strength of the results by Gluck and others.  @EnhaoLan]

Comment: Yes, But I've rarely seen geometric problems directly translated into PDE problems  before.  The paper of '74 also state that for $S^2$, the sufficient condition of  existence of metric for perscribed Gauss curvature is unknow.  Chow (The Ricci flow on the 2-sphere) has a paper state that the Gauss curvature will become positive under normalized Ricci flow. It might work.  (I just thought of it. )

Comment: Yes but the Ricci flow will certainly not preserve the critical points of $K$.  So I don't know what the answer would be if one requires that $K$ is negative somewhere.  @EnhaoLan

Comment: Yes. I know so little. These questions are not suitable for me now, I have to accumulate enough first. Thanks.